# Making intranet accessible for a user on the outisde

Tags: sharepoint-server, dns, intranet, extranet, extended

At the moment I have a Enterprise Wiki in SharePoint 2013 server to use as a knowledge base. I can add all my users from the Active Directory to access the SharePoint site within the domain. Now I want to be able to add users and set a site (

```
http://www.kb-inside.com ? )
```

because i dont think the normal URL will work (

```
http://ins-sp2013/ )?
```

Users should be able to access this knowledge base as they
 visit customers. How do I accomplish this, I am new to SharePoint.

Thanks !

Kevin

Answer (score 3):

Follow the below steps::

first read this article about **Extend** web applications in : [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287954%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276325.aspx)

but if you can learn how to configure it like professionals:

1. design : you can design and configure security devices like  : firewall - Router - DNS ... ( add A record to DNS server of your [internet hosting domain DNS management](https://www.hioxindia.com/faq/domain-hosting/add-dns-linux.php) and [local](http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1954305/adding-dns-host-record-windows-server-2012-dns-server.html))
2. configure it for higher security with firewall or TMG or kerio or ISA Server or other solutions : this [article](http://www.isaserver.org/articles-tutorials/publishing/How-to-Publish-Microsoft-Sharepoint-Service-ISA-Server-2006.html)
3. access the site by grant permission to your target audience :  this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608071.aspx)

Comment: I tried to do this using the article you provided. It didn't help i can't acces my URL. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: please check your firewall and test your routing path from internet and trace and ask administrator to open ports.

Comment: please check the dns and iis and thier configurations you should check and test again to apply them correctly. or restart the server. or use iisreset